# can we use string function in replace function in sql while updating a record

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, concatenation

I want to update my record on certain conditions.

eg. I've a column ResidenceAddress1, which has email id along with the address.

Sample data:

```
sap3200@gmail.com,Rourkela   
sap3212@gmail.com 2nd street,7 hills    
2nd street, sap3212@gmail.com
```

I am finding the email from ResidenceAddress1 this way:

```
select (concat(trim(substring_index(substring_index(Residence_Address1, '@', '1'), ' ', -1)),'','@gmail.com') as mail,Residence_Address1
from mytable
where Residence_Address1 like '%gmail%' and Email_Personal1=""
```

When I update it this way:

```
update mytable
set email_Personal1=concat(trim(substring_index(substring_index(Residence_Address1, '@', '1'), ' ', -1)), '','@gmail.com') , 
                 Residence_Address1=replace(residence_address1,"'concat(trim(substring_index(substring_index(Residence_Address1, '@', '1'), ' ', -1)), '','@gmail.com')'",'')
where Residence_Address1 like '%gmail%' and Email_Personal1=""
```

This way, it updates email_personal1 but didn't update residence_address1 with replaced empty value instead of gmail id value in that row. Where am I mistaking here?

Answer (score 1):

You can update multiple columns and mix string functions in an `update`.  In the question, you have extra double quotes, which are not needed.  Perhaps you intend something like this:

```
update fulldata_table
    set email_Personal1 = concat(trim(substring_index(substring_index(Residence_Address1, '@', '1'
                                       ), ' ', -1)
       ), '', '@gmail.com'), 
        Residence_Address1 = replace(residence_address1, concat(trim(substring_index(substring_index(Residence_Address1, '@', '1'), ' ', -1)), '', '@gmail.com', '')
    where Residence_Address1 like '%gmail%' and Email_Personal1 = ''
```

Comment: Thanks. But its giving me syntax error. Generally for replace function, the syntax is: replace(fieldname,'string needs to be replaced', 'replaced with this' ) that is replace (fieldname,'string1','string2') . Then shall i need to put whole second part starting with concat in single quote?

Comment: While setting up single quote in the second part of replace, it looks very complicated. That's why I have added double quotes for second part.

Comment: @iks_in . . . You cannot use double quotes that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE fulldata_table SET
  email_Personal1 = concat(trim(substring_index(substring_index(Residence_Address1, '@', '1'),' ',-1 ) ), '@gmail.com') ,
  Residence_Address1 = replace( residence_address1, concat( trim( substring_index( substring_index(Residence_Address1, '@', '1'), ' ', -1 ) ), '@gmail.com', '' ), '' )
WHERE Residence_Address1 LIKE '%gmail%' AND Email_Personal1 = '';
```

Comment: Thanks. But it returned 12,388 rows out of 13,401 rows. It didn't work for remaining 1013 rows.

Comment: These are probably excluded by the where clause. You could check these cases, and why they don't fit by running: `select * from fulldata_table where not (Residence_Address1 LIKE '%gmail%' AND Email_Personal1 = '');`